# How to prove functions equal, knowing their bodies are equal?

Tags: coq, proof

How can we prove the following?:

```
Lemma forfun: forall (A B : nat->nat), (forall x:nat, A x = B x) ->
                                       (fun x => A x) = (fun x => B x).
Proof.
```

Comment: @HoboSapiens This is a legitimate question about programming in the Coq proof assistant, cf. other related questions on the Coq tag.

Comment: @HoboSapiens: coq is an automated theorem prover, which is also a programming language.  (Hover over the `coq` tag: 186 followers and 410 questions here on SO.)  This question is about how to use the coq language, not how to prove a general mathematical fact.  That said, I don't think it would be out of place on Math.SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The principle you want is known as *functional extensionality*; in its most general form, it says

```
Axiom fun_ext : forall (A B : Type) (f g : A -> B),
  (forall x : A, f x = g x) -> f = g.
```

Unfortunately, in spite of being useful, this principle is *independent* of Coq's base logic, which means that it is not possible to prove it or refute it. However, Coq's logic was designed so that it would be safe to assume this principle as an axiom in the theory, and [Coq's standard library](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/stdlib/Coq.Logic.FunctionalExtensionality.html) already has that principle defined so that you can use it.